# std::sort doing lots of unnecessary swaps

Tags: c++

I have the following code where I try a lexicographical comparison of two simple vectors

```
class ExpensiveClass {
public:
  static int increment;
  std::vector<int> bigVector;

  ExpensiveClass() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1 + increment; ++j)
      bigVector.emplace_back(j);
    ++increment;
  }
  ExpensiveClass(const ExpensiveClass& other) {
    std::cout << "Expensive copy constructor called!" << std::endl;
    this->bigVector = other.bigVector;
  }
};

int ExpensiveClass::increment = 0;

bool sortFunc(const ExpensiveClass& a, const ExpensiveClass& b) {
  bool ret = a.bigVector < b.bigVector;
  if (ret == false)
    std::cout << "Need to swap" << std::endl;
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<ExpensiveClass> vectorOfVectors;
  vectorOfVectors.reserve(100);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    vectorOfVectors.emplace_back();

  std::cout << "Start sorting.." << std::endl;
  std::sort(vectorOfVectors.begin(), vectorOfVectors.end(), sortFunc);
}
```

and I'd like to know why is `std::sort` doing lots of swaps even on a sorted vector?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but `std::vector<ExpensiveClass> vectorOfVectors;
  vectorOfVectors.reserve(100);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    vectorOfVectors.emplace_back();` can be done with `std::vector<ExpensiveClass> vectorOfVectors(100);`

Comment: Are you really sure the algorithm call a swap each time you print "Need to swap" ?

Comment: A comparison result of false doesn't mean a swap is imminent.

Comment: I tested it with clang, the code is above and can be reproduced. Also: the copy constructor is called each time

Comment: The sort algorithm *could* check if the range is sorted first, but that would incur an extra cost for all the cases where the range isn't sorted. If sorting already sorted ranges is the norm for you, you can use `std::is_sorted` before sorting.

Comment: [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53f9737c031a7a95) doesn't actually swap.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we're getting into dark corners of STL here. I played with your code and discovered that your `sortFunc()` doesn't always return `true`. This is because the arguments being passed are not in order. The `std::sort` algorithm picks elements from your `vectorOfVectors` that are out of order, i.e. it the index of `a` within `vectorOfVectors` is not guaranteed to be higher than the index of `b`. But I don't know how to dig deeper into this so I created a separate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539898/counter-intuitive-behavior-of-stdsort

Anyway, my point is that you made some assumption on the behavior of `std::sort`, however that's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Many sorting algorithms that perform well on average compare input container elements not in order for various reasons, for example to randomize over various inputs to produce good average time complexity, or to pivot swaps around a median threshold, etc.

There are a few other algorithms (such as mergesort and heapsort) that start by copying elements and creating auxilary structure; for them you can count on every array element copied at least once. These algorithms produce guaranteed asymptotically optimal worst case performance at the expense of subpar average case performance.

stl::sort does not guarantee which sorting algorithm it will use. In fact, some STL implementations use two different algorithms: start with an algorithm with a good average case performance (but lousy worst case), and if the algorithm doesn't finish quickly enough stl::sort switches to a slower average case algorithm with a guaranteed asymptotically optimal worst case performance.

On the other hand, STL provides you with multiple options on how to sort your container: besides stl::sort (which is designed to perform well) you have stl::stable_sort (that preserves relative order of equivalent elements), stl::partial_sort, etc.

I think in your case you may prefer stl::stable_sort. This one guarantees that there will be no swaps between elements that already are in the right order. I doubt that stl::stable_sort actually minimizes the number of swaps, but it should be swapping less than stl::sort.